# Strings as arguments for macros in C++

Tags: c++, macros, g++

Say I have something like this:

```
#include <iostream>  
#define OUTPUT(i) std::cout.operator<<(i)
using std::endl;


void main(){
string str("Test");
OUTPUT(str) << endl;
}
```

I ran it in g++ and it compiled, but it output what appears to be the address of the string.  I looked up how to do this but it gives me an operator for Microsoft C (the `#` operator apparently) which, when I tested it, gave the same output as if it didn't have the `#`.  I wonder if this is possible.  Can Macro parameters *only* be integral, or should I pass it a pointer to a char array for output.

Edit:

That code has pretty blatant syntax errors.  Let me try again.

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <string>
#define OUTPUT(i) std::cout.operator<<(i)
using std::endl;
using std::string;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //string str("Test");
    OUTPUT("Test") << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just `#define OUTPUT(i) std::cout << i`

Comment: Even with some basic fixes [your code doesn't compile at all](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d2173bba361ef9cc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no such thing like a

```
 std::cout.operator<<(i)
```

where `i` isn't an integral type.

There's an overload for the global [`ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const T&)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2).

For integral types it should work, as `std::ostream` provides [overloads for these types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt).

---

As mentioned in comments just define your macro as

```
 #define OUTPUT(i) std::cout << (i)
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/50618d20849bd8e1)

I don't see much point doing so though.

Comment: not true. the standard defines operator<< for intrinsic types as a member of ostream.

Comment: Wow it worked that time.  Thanks.  I thought both were equivalent but apparently it doesn't like when I use `operator<<()`.

Comment: @RichardHodges Well, it obviously didn't work with `std::cout` as mentioned [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d2173bba361ef9cc).

Comment: Also, `std::cout.operator<<(i)` does work for integral types, like I tried `OUTPUT(10)` and it output 10 to the console.  but when I passed a string literal, it didn't like it.

Comment: @Zackeezy Clarified about that last point. For integral types, there actually are overloads for the `operator<<()`.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ So the issue is that for STL data types like String or for c-style strings there is no overload?

Comment: @Zackeezy operator<< is defined as a member function for intrinsic types AND as a free-function overload for various Ts.

Comment: @Zackeezy Yes, that seems to be the problem. Anyways the proposed solution will cover any types that have an appropriate global `operator<<()` overload.

Comment: I have been under the assumption that `operator(i)` and `<< i` were equivalent.  Is this to say they aren't?

Comment: @Zackeezy No they aren't, in case of `std::cout.operator<<(i)` a member function is called explicitely, wheras `std::cout << i;` may call both either a member function, or a matching global overload of the `operator<<()` function.

Comment: and with the former there's no chance of calling an overloaded version, since it's explicitly from `std::cout`?

Comment: @Zackeezy _"and with the former there's no chance of calling an overloaded version ..."_ Yes, exactly.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I get it now.

Comment: "There's no such thing like a std::cout.operator<<(i)
where i isn't an integral type.". Well, the example shows otherwise. There is such an overload, and it's the member `operator<<(void* p)`. This indeed prints the address `p`. And `void*` is not an integral type.